# How to disable user from accessing your SharePoint 2007 Site using a mobile devices

Tags: mobile

Are there any options that I can restrict user(s) who use a mobile device (tablet or handphone / mobile phone) from accessing some of my SharePoint 2007 site(s)?

This is because I only want most of my SharePoint 2007 site to be constrain to desktop or laptop machine(s), while the rest of them are allowed to be access via a mobile devices such as a tablet (e.g. Samsung Galaxy Tablet / IPad) or a mobile phone (e.g. Samsung Galaxy S3 / IPhone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the mobile device is easy.

try the following:

goto:

C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\5497\App_Browsers

you should see a file called "compat.browser". open it up using notepad or word and edit the part that says "isMobileDevice" , search for it and set the value to "false";

now goto stsadm and type the following:

```
stsadm -o deactivatefeature -name MobilityRedirect -URL http://yourSiteURL.com
```

press enter and you should see "Operation completed successfully"

obviously http://yourSiteURL.com is what ever your site is called like https://uk2010.dev.com so my example would be:

```
stsadm -o deactivatefeature -name MobilityRedirect -URL https://uk2010.dev.com
```

That should be it! hope it helps :)

Comment: The folder `5497` (for `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\5497\App_Browsers`) is actually the port number of the website right? But I could not find this folder `5497`. However, I found other folders with other numbers, so, which one should I be accessing?

Comment: Also, I notice that there are many parts that contain `isMobileDevice` when I select the `80` directory path. Should I change **all** the `isMobileDevice` to false?

Comment: the folder that you need should contain "_app_bin", "_vti_pvt", App_GlobalResources", "Aspnet_client", "bin", "wpresources" and "App_Browser". the last one is the one you need and should only contain a file called "compat.browser", there should be only one folder that contains all those folders among other files. yes any part that you see is called IsMobileDevice set its value to false rather then true!